# How can I make txt files with some script with Batch files?

Tags: batch

By using batch files, I want to make some .settings files with some script below.
And I already got script below to make some files with batch.

```
@echo bla bla > app.settings
```

But with this code, I can not type script like below.

```
  <ServerClientSettings>
<IsServer>false</IsServer>
<ServerIP>255.255.255.255:65535</ServerIP>
<ServerTimeout>20000</ServerTimeout>
<ClientList />
```

Can you guys give me some advice to make it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about creating a multi-line text-file in batch with
special characters, you may uses the append operator `>>` and
the escape operator `^`, like this :

```
echo ^<ServerClientSettings^> >f.txt
echo   ^<IsServer^>false^</IsServer^> >>f.txt
echo   ^<ServerIP^>255.255.255.255:65535^</ServerIP^> >>f.txt
echo   ^<ServerTimeout^>20000^</ServerTimeout^> >>f.txt
echo ^<ClientList /^> >>f.txt
```

References :

- [How-to: Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- [How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)
- [echo command](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your code also worked. But I want to know how to make line like this (line 2,3,4,5,6 is subordinate line of line 1)

Comment: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/1500/L2SoNq.png

Comment: Just add blanks. I modified the answer.